# Find whether checkbox is checked in php

Tags: php

This question has been asked before but i used the same thing as said in the answer to the question but it is not working
My form:

```
$home=  
    "<div class='heading'  >
        <p><b>EHD HOME AUTOMATION</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-wrap'>
        <nav class='menu'>
            <ul class='clearfix'>
                <li><a href='./member.php'>$username's Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>States <span class='arrow'>&#9660;</span></a>

                    <ul class='sub-menu'>
                        <li><a href='#' onclick='changeAllStatesToFalse();'>ALL APPLIANCES OFF</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' onclick='changeAllStatesToTrue();'>ALL APPLIANCES ON</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' onclick='getStates();'>GET STATES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#'>Security</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Page info</a></li>
                <li><a href='./logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!3 Toggle Buttons start>
        <div class='buttonsArea'>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      Appliance 1
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button1' name='A1'/>
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      Appliance 2
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button2' onclick='updateTable(2);'/>
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      Appliance 3
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button3' onclick='updateTable(3);' />
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!3 Toggle Buttons end>";

    if(isset($_POST['A1'])){
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('A1 pressed');</script>";
    }

    if($username && $userid){

        echo "$home";

        if($errormsg)
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
    }
```

The checkbox A1 is not responding to isset function. No matter set or not set nothing echo's.
Please help
See the 3 toggle button division

Comment: Set a value for the checkbox.

Comment: controls being sent from a form need to have a value. Checkboxs and radiobuttons need something checked first so the server-side language can pick up a value. Change your html <input type="checkbox" checked> to see how this works.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis isset function should work on checkbox even without giving a value attribute. Check your post with var_dump($_POST).

Comment: Hi, once set a value for the checkbox `A1` and try...